# JCurses colors not working

Tags: java, colors, console-application, jcurses

I'm just getting started developing my first console application with JCurses. So far I can get a window to display with a couple buttons, but there is no visual differentiation between the focused and unfocused buttons.

It appears from the source that the focused buttons should have different colors out of the box, and I've also tried explicitly setting different colors for focused buttons using `Button.setFocusedButtonColors` with no effect.

Can anyone who has used JCurses either tell me what I need to do in my app to enable colors, or confirm that this is a terminal emulation problem? (I have used colors successfully in the same terminal by printing the escape codes from a perl program.)